# error <No method asJSON S3 class: difftime> in R plumber

Tags: r

I faced some issues regarding difftime in R plumber API. Tried with R, it works normally. However, when turned to API, its returned "

## with R plumber

```
#' @param lease_start date 
#' @param lease_end date 
#' @post /difference
function(lease_start, lease_end){
  lease_start <- as.Date("01/01/2018", format = "%d/%m/%Y")
  lease_end <- as.Date("01/01/2019", format = "%d/%m/%Y")
  lease_end <- as.Date(lease_end,  ",  "%d/%m/%Y")
  difference <- lease_end - lease_start
  difference
}
```

## Result:

> simpleError: No method asJSON S3 class: difftime

Anyone knows what is the issue and how to fix it? Thank you a lot!

Comment: In your posted code you start a string in lease_end, but never close it. Either a copy paste error. Or already your error ;-)

Comment: hi Linus, my bad when copying the code to here. I added the exact code which I used in the below. thanks

Answer (score 2):

To return an R object to an API client, {plumber} translates the object
into a format that can be understood by the API client. This process is called
“serialization” [Rendering output with Plumber](https://www.rplumber.io/articles/rendering-output.html#serializers-1).
By default, {plumber} uses JSON serialization and {jsonlite} R package
to turn R objects into JSON.

As explained by @Steve, in R, difference of two dates returns
a difftime object that cannot be processed into JSON. {jsonlite} raises, then,
the error mentioned in the question as shown with the following code

```r
library(plumber)
library(jsonlite)

lease_start <- as.Date("01/01/2018", format = "%d/%m/%Y")
lease_end <- as.Date("01/01/2019",  format = "%d/%m/%Y")
difference <- lease_end - lease_start

class(difference)
#> [1] "difftime"
jsonlite::toJSON(difference)
#> Error: No method asJSON S3 class: difftime
```

One solution is to convert difftime object into a number or character.
In this way, the object can be converted to JSON:

```r
jsonlite::toJSON(as.numeric(difference))
#> [365]
jsonlite::toJSON(as.character(difference))
#> ["365"]
```

An alternative solution consists in controlling the serialization to return
a text object via `print()`, `format()` or `cat()`. This can be done adding
alternative serializers provided by {plumber}

```r
#* @param lease_start date
#* @param lease_end date
#* @serializer format
#* @post /difference_format
function(lease_start = "01/01/2018", lease_end="01/01/2019"){
  lease_start <- as.Date(lease_start, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
  lease_end <- as.Date(lease_end,  format = "%d/%m/%Y")
  difference <- lease_end - lease_start
  difference
}
```

In a similar way, you can use `@serializer cat` or `@serializer print`

Nevertheless, the solution I prefer is to return difftime object two parts (units and actual difference value) in a list.

```r
list(units = units(difference), value = as.numeric(difference))
#> $units
#> [1] "days"
#> 
#> $value
#> [1] 365
```

The advantage is that lists can be processed by {plumber} default serializer
and no error will be raised

```r
jsonlite::toJSON(list(units = units(difference), value = as.numeric(difference)))
#> {"units":["days"],"value":[365]}

#* @param lease_start date
#* @param lease_end date
#* @post /difference
function(lease_start = "01/01/2018", lease_end="01/01/2019"){
  lease_start <- as.Date(lease_start, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
  lease_end <- as.Date(lease_end,  format = "%d/%m/%Y")
  difference <- lease_end - lease_start
  list(units = units(difference), value = as.numeric(difference))
}
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my bad for copying the code: 
the exact code is below:

```
#* @param lease_start date 
#* @param lease_end date
#* @post/difference

function(lease_start, lease_end){
    lease_start <- as.Date("01/01/2018", format = "%d/%m/%Y")
     lease_end <- as.Date("01/01/2019",  format = "%d/%m/%Y")
  difference <- lease_end - lease_start
  difference
}
```

the code works well without turning to API with the result is 365 days. With the above-mentioned code, it gave me the error ""

Answer (score 1):

this line -- `difference <- lease_end - lease_start` will create a R specific object called `difftime` which cannot be properly parsed by Plumber.

you can try at the end convert `difference` to character or integer by `as.character(difference)`  or `as.integer(difference)` and it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can use force =True when returning json output     `toJSON(difference,force = TRUE)`